# Sublime not highlighting html syntax error

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

The below html has an error which isn't picked up by sublime text's syntax highlighting.

```
<div class="container">
    <img class"left" src="/static/img/product.jpg"/>
    <div class="right">
        <h2 class="caps">Product Name</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the code in Sublime]

It took me ages to find that error. In an IDE like Visual Studio, the editor would highlight it like below.

[image: Screenshot of the code in Visual Studio]

It seems Sublime doesn't highlight these errors by default. Is there a setting somewhere to make Sublime intelligent enough to highlight these errors?

Comment: It isn't implemented in Sublime, that's all. I don't know what answer you expect here.

Comment: Is there any way to give sublime that functionality?

Comment: maybe Linter package, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime just doesn't have that functionality as a part of the syntax highlighting functionality. You want to use a package like https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2 to acheive this.